# condition purpose not explicit

Tags: bash, variables

I have the following function:

```
function any_name() { 


 local arg1=$1

  shift

  local arg2=$1

  shift

  local arg3=$1 

  if [[ "$arg1" -eq 0 ]]; then 
     ${arg2} ${arg3} 

     if [[ "$?" -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo"${msg}"
     else
        echo "${msg}"
     fi
  else
     echo "${msg}"
  fi
```

}

In this case precisely, what does mean 'then ${arg2} ${arg3}' ?
It's not a command neither a variable initialization. I just cannot understand the purpose of such condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a command.

```
arg2="ls"
arg3="-l"
${arg2} ${arg3}  # Same as ls -l
```

Comment: this is what I thought but:

Comment: Of course, since the expansion of `arg2` is unquoted, if the variable contained more than one word, only the first of those would be the command.